# Как предотвратить залезание div под div

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Здравствуйте. Я ставлю блоки которые при уменьшении изображения должны сдвигаться друг под друга, но не должны заползать под меню которое справа. Можно поставить что бы блок в котором содержатся остальные блоки (те что маленькие) в процентном соотношении, аля-87%, но все равно когда я размер окна уменьшаю, то основной блок залезает под меню и происходит все сначала.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И так же при добавлении в блоке overlow: auto; не появляется прокрутка.

Comment: Код добавьте к вопросу, пожалуйста. Иначе ответ может звучать только как очень неопределенно. Примерно как дальше) Если у вас основное меню с позишн абсолют/фиксед - сделайте темной "шапке" ширину 100% и паддинг-райт = ширине правого меню.

Answer (score 2):

Используй `bootstrap` для создания адаптивной верстки.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               <!--Block #1 -->
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 block equal">
                   <!-- Block #1 -->
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 block i1">
                        <h1>block 1</h1>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Block #2 -->
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 block i2">
                        <h1>block 2</h1>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Block #3 -->
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 block i3">
                        <h1>block 3</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--Block #4 -->
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 block i4">
                    <h1>block 4</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.block {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.i1 {
    min-height: 200px;
}

.i2 {
    min-height: 200px;
}

.i3 {
    min-height: 700px;
}

.i4 {
    min-height: 1100px;
}

.equal {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}
```

Не забудь подключить библиотеку c CSS от `Bootstrap`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

По поводу `overflow:auto` :

- Сначала тебе нужно указать `min-height` для блока
- Указать `overflow:auto`
- Прокрутка появиться тогда, когда высота контента блока больше указанного `min-height`
- Если нужно прокрутку раньше, уменьши `min-height` (Пункт №1)